# How to change the height of a `<Div>` and its parent `<Td>`

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following mark-up inside a third part application. now for this third part application, I can write custom JavaScript and custom css against the generated markup.

```
<td style="height:75px">
        <div style="height: 75px; opacity: 0.99;" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl40_g_79ca5882_ef72_482a_9f70_94b4a8c6804e_text">
        <span id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl40_g_79ca5882_ef72_482a_9f70_94b4a8c6804e_title" class="ms-slideshow-title"></span><br>
        </div>
</td>
```

So how I can modify the height property, for the `<div>` and its parent `<td>` from `style="height:75px"` to `style="height:0px"`??

Comment: With `height: 0px !important;` in css? Or just `max-height: 0;`, as it overrides `height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would select all `<td>` elements, and all `<div>` elements that are directly inside a `<td>` and make their height `0px`

```
$("td, td > div").height(0);
```

Try this first, but, I suspect this will select more things than you intend it to depending on what else is on this page.

If all the div elements have an ID that begins with `MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart` then you can start from there by selecting all of those, and then finding the parent elements.  Check [the jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for how to do partial attribute matching.

```
$("div[id^='MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart']").each(function() {
  $(this).height(0).parent().height(0);
});
```

Comment: `$("div[id^='MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart']").each(function() {
  $(this).height(0).parent().height(0);
}); ` did the job. need to test it in wider browsers ,, will let u  know accordingly

Comment: glad to hear it!  If that works, than you can remove the `.each()` because it will be slightly slower than just using `$("div[id^='MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart']").height(0).parent().height(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)!
You can find each `<td>`, and use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `<div>` element inside of it.

```
$('td').each(function(){
  $(this).css('height', '0px');
  $(this).find('div').css('height', '0px');
});
```

Comment: @M Jr but your script will affect all div and td .. while I want to only change the one showed inside my markup, mainly based on the Div id

Comment: I know, when I was about to update this option, Chris Barr posted his answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use set `max-height:0` to the elements to set height 0 using your parent class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
td,
div {
  background: red;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<td style="height:75px">
  <div style="height: 75px; opacity: 0.99;" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl40_g_79ca5882_ef72_482a_9f70_94b4a8c6804e_text">
    <span id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl40_g_79ca5882_ef72_482a_9f70_94b4a8c6804e_title" class="ms-slideshow-title"></span><br>
  </div>
</td>
```